# Angular nested directive render via ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-directive

I have a directive that is used to render a single user's details.

```
<user-directive></user-directive/>
```

I have another directive that nests a repeated collection on the user-directive.

```
<!-- has some other stuff then the user collection -->
<user-directive ng-repeat="user in vm.users" user="user"></user-directive>
```

I've tried setting the **scope** in the single user directive but I can't seem to get the template to populate with the user data from the repeater.

**User directive object:**

```
return {
          // template etc
          scope : { user: '=' }
       }
```

**User directive template:**

```
<h1>{{user.name}}</h1>
```

Any ideas?

Refer [fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/shashank2691/f89de242/) for reproducing the effect.

Comment: can you provide a fiddle or a plunkr with hard coded user data into and array or something?

Comment: Perhaps you should change the name of `user in vm.users` (maybe to `describedUser` or something like that), as it seems to collide with the `user` from the directive

Comment: @JohnDoe that makes no sense...OP is trying to access the same `user` that `ng-repeat` creates

Comment: @charlietfl I thought the directive's `user` could be taking precedence, which would make the properties different, and could be excluding `name`.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. Perhaps provide a plunkr or jsbin with all the code in any case. The devil's in the details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refer the sample [here](https://jsfiddle.net/shashank2691/kx4s6pq0/2/).

**Code:**

*HTML:*

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="test as vm">
    <div test-dir="user" ng-repeat="user in vm.users">
    </div>
</div>
```

*JS:*

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('test', function ($scope) {
    var vm = this;
    vm.users = [
     { 'Name': 'Abc', 'Id': 1 }, { 'Name': 'Pqr', 'Id': 2 }, { 'Name': 'XYZ', 'Id': 3 }
    ];

    $scope = vm;
});

app.directive('testDir', function () {
    return {
        scope: { user: '=testDir' },
        template: "<div><h4>{{user.Id}}) {{user.Name}}</h4></div>"
    }
});
```